# How to Detect whether an Element Has ::after (Pseudo-Element)?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Suppose an `input` element has pseudo-element `::after` at the end of that element, and after that there is a button, i.e. there is pseudo-element `::after` between an `input` element and a `button` element. For example please look at the below picture-

[image]

In above example, when the `button` is clicked, after some time, the `input` is changed and the `::after` pseudo-element gets vanished.

How can I detect that the input has `::after` or not?

Comment: I think it's not possible in javascript. You can try something like this if the pseudo element has a style associated with it. var color = window.getComputedStyle(
 document.querySelector('.element'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('any_style_property_value').
If the value returned is undefined, it doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle(el, '::after').content` to get the content of the `::after` pseudo-element (it works for `::before` as well). If the content is not the `none`, the pseudo-element exists.

```js
const hasAfter = selector => {
  const el = document.querySelector(selector);
   
  return getComputedStyle(el, '::after').content !== 'none';
}


console.log(hasAfter('.has')); // true
console.log(hasAfter('.hasnt')); // false
```

```css
.has::after {
  content: 'after';
}
```

```html
<p class="has">has </p>

<p class="hasnt">hasn't</p>
```

Comment: how can I modify  ``document.addEventListener('click',function (event) {
console.log(event.target.tagName); 
}, false);`` if I wnat to know the that the clicked elemnt has ``::after`` or not?

Comment: Replace `el` in my code with the `event.target` - `document.addEventListener('click',function (event) { console.log(getComputedStyle(event.target, '::after').content !== 'none'); }, false);`

Comment: that ``::after`` has an attribute ``canFocus`` which is either true or false, this attribute gets value from server/internet, can I get the value of ``canFocus`` ?

Comment: @Mike - I'm not sure what you're asking. You should open a new question with the relevant code.